# Mini disk of a blackhole meaning

Tags: black-hole, gravity, accretion-discs

What is meant by the "mini disk" of a blackhole? Is it the same as accretion disk? If not, whats the difference?

Eg: In the abstract of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05697 it is mentioned "When the accretion rate is relatively high, the circumbinary disk, accretion streams, and mini-disks combine to emit light in the UV/EUV bands"

Comment: Can you put some link, where did you read it? I never heard from this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paper, [Quasi-Periodic Behavior of Mini-Disks in Binary Black Holes Approaching Merger](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05451), which shares authors with the paper linked in the question, sheds some light on the terminology.

> We present the first magnetohydrodynamic simulation in which a
>   circumbinary disk around a relativistic binary black hole feeds mass
>   to individual accretion disks ("mini-disks") around each black hole.

They are talking about active binary black hole systems. The system as a whole has an accretion disk, the circumbinary disk, and each black hole has its own accretion disk, which they call the mini-disk.